# Pipeline deploy to android APK to app store

Tags: android, android-build, bitbucket-pipelines

I currently use bitbucket as my repo for my react native android projects, bitbucket has pipelines which allow me to build an apk. However, I cannot find or figure out how it then automatically deploy this to the play store via the playstores api. Could anyone one point me in the right direction? Thanks.